# iptables see ips in portscan prevention

Tags: linux, security, iptables, port

I do have the following iptables rules to prevent port scanning on my server:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m set ! --match-set scanned_ports src,dst -m hashlimit --hashlimit-above 1/hour --hashlimit-burst 5 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name portscan --hashlimit-htable-expire 10000 -j SET --add-set port_scanners src --exist
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m set --match-set port_scanners src -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -j SET --add-set scanned_ports src,dst
```

How can I see what ips are locked right now? I want to write a script that logs any ips that tried to do a port scan.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Logging is built into iptables. Lookup iptables LOGGING it is fairly easy to set up.
Something like this will grab all dropped ip address and put in /var/log/messages.

```
iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Dropped: " --log-level 4
iptables -A LOGGING -j DROP
```

default it will go to /var/log/messages but you can redirect to something else by adding the following to /etc/syslog.conf and then touch /var/log/dropped.log

> kern.warning   /var/log/dropped.log

Comment: I just tried it, but it made my server unreachable.. had to restart it

Comment: all this does is set up logging. it blocks nothing and shouldn't have caused you to be locked out. Please look up more about logging in iptables. it is not hard but has been fully documented on redhat.com centos.org and and various other sites.Here is a sample from Centos forum https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=44666